# JavaFX getResource not loading FXML

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to load a FXML file into a JavaFX controller with the following code:

```
loader.setLocation(BaseController.class.getResource("/baseLayout.fxml"));
baseLayout = loader.load();
```

But I'm getting this exception instead:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

The problem is that `getResource` is not loading the FXML correctly, so `setLocation` receives `null` as parameter and I get the exception running `loader.load()`

What I've seen in some answers around there, is that the problem might be with wrong path in getResource. But, as far as I know, "/baseLayout.fxml" should point to the respectively fxml file inside the resources folder.

Here is my project file tree:

> - project/
>
>   - src/
>
>     - main/
>
>       - java/
>       - resources/
>
>         - baseLayout.fxml

Isn't it supposed to work? I was actually working just fine, but suddenly it's not. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: That should work, as long as your resources folder is getting deployed to the root of the classpath. Check the content of your build folder to make sure the FMXL file is there.

Comment: I think maybe that's the problem, I don't see the FXML files. Why they are not getting deployed?

Comment: That's an IDE setting, so it depends on your IDE. You'll need to go to the setting for the project and make sure that the resources folder is included in the build (and perhaps that FXML files are copied to the deployment).

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the fxml like this

```
loader.setLocation(BaseController.class.getResource("/resources/baseLayout.fxml"));
```

or

```
loader.setLocation(BaseController.class.getResource("../resources/baseLayout.fxml"));
```

But before this as @James_D mentioned Please check weather the resultant jar contains the resources folder i:e weather it is present in the build or not.